# How to include inlinecount with odata response in Mule?

Tags: mule, odata, apikit

I'm using the odata example from https://github.com/mulesoft/apikit-odata-example.

When I include the inlinecount filter (see my request below), the count is not returned with the results. How do I add the count to the response?

Request: http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers?$format=json&$inlinecount=allpages

Response:

```
{
 "d": {
     "results": [
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
             "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": ""
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('ALFKI')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
             "ContactName": "Maria Anders",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "ALFKI"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('ANATR')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
             "ContactName": "Ana Trujillo",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "ANATR"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('ANTON')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Antonio Moreno Taquera",
             "ContactName": "Antonio Moreno",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "ANTON"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('AROUT')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Around the Horn",
             "ContactName": "Thomas Hardy",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "AROUT"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BERGS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Berglunds snabbkp",
             "ContactName": "Christina Berglund",
             "ContactTitle": "Order Administrator",
             "CustomerID": "BERGS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BLAUS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
             "ContactName": "Hanna Moos",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "BLAUS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BLONP')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Blondesddsl pre et fils",
             "ContactName": "Frdrique Citeaux",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "BLONP"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BOLID')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Blido Comidas preparadas",
             "ContactName": "Martn Sommer",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "BOLID"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BONAP')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Bon app'",
             "ContactName": "Laurence Lebihan",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "BONAP"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BOTTM')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Bottom-Dollar Markets",
             "ContactName": "Elizabeth Lincoln",
             "ContactTitle": "Accounting Manager",
             "CustomerID": "BOTTM"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('BSBEV')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "B's Beverages",
             "ContactName": "Victoria Ashworth",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "BSBEV"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('CACTU')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
             "ContactName": "Patricio Simpson",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Agent",
             "CustomerID": "CACTU"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('CENTC')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
             "ContactName": "Francisco Chang",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "CENTC"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('CHOPS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Chop-suey Chinese",
             "ContactName": "Yang Wang",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "CHOPS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('COMMI')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Comrcio Mineiro",
             "ContactName": "Pedro Afonso",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Associate",
             "CustomerID": "COMMI"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('CONSH')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Consolidated Holdings",
             "ContactName": "Elizabeth Brown",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "CONSH"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('DRACD')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Drachenblut Delikatessen",
             "ContactName": "Sven Ottlieb",
             "ContactTitle": "Order Administrator",
             "CustomerID": "DRACD"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('DUMON')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Du monde entier",
             "ContactName": "Janine Labrune",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "DUMON"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('EASTC')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Eastern Connection",
             "ContactName": "Ann Devon",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Agent",
             "CustomerID": "EASTC"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('ERNSH')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Ernst Handel",
             "ContactName": "Roland Mendel",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager",
             "CustomerID": "ERNSH"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FAMIA')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Familia Arquibaldo",
             "ContactName": "Aria Cruz",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Assistant",
             "CustomerID": "FAMIA"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FANT')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Fantasma",
             "ContactName": "Casper",
             "ContactTitle": "Evasor Profesional",
             "CustomerID": "FANT"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FISSA')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A.",
             "ContactName": "Diego Roel",
             "ContactTitle": "Accounting Manager",
             "CustomerID": "FISSA"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FOLIG')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Folies gourmandes",
             "ContactName": "Martine Ranc",
             "ContactTitle": "Assistant Sales Agent",
             "CustomerID": "FOLIG"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FOLKO')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Folk och f HB",
             "ContactName": "Maria Larsson",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "FOLKO"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FRANK')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Frankenversand",
             "ContactName": "Peter Franken",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "FRANK"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FRANR')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "France restauration",
             "ContactName": "Carine Schmitt",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "FRANR"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FRANS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Franchi S.p.A.",
             "ContactName": "Paolo Accorti",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "FRANS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('FURIB')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Furia Bacalhau e Frutos do Mar",
             "ContactName": "Lino Rodriguez",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager",
             "CustomerID": "FURIB"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('GALED')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Galera del gastrnomo",
             "ContactName": "Eduardo Saavedra",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "GALED"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('GODOS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Godos Cocina Tpica",
             "ContactName": "Jos Pedro Freyre",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager",
             "CustomerID": "GODOS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('GOURL')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Gourmet Lanchonetes",
             "ContactName": "Andr Fonseca",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Associate",
             "CustomerID": "GOURL"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('GREAL')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Great Lakes Food Market",
             "ContactName": "Howard Snyder",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "GREAL"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('GROSR')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "GROSELLA-Restaurante",
             "ContactName": "Manuel Pereira",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "GROSR"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('HANAR')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Hanari Carnes",
             "ContactName": "Mario Pontes",
             "ContactTitle": "Accounting Manager",
             "CustomerID": "HANAR"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('HILAA')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "HILARION-Abastos",
             "ContactName": "Carlos Hernndez",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "HILAA"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('HUNGC')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Hungry Coyote Import Store",
             "ContactName": "Yoshi Latimer",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "HUNGC"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('HUNGO')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Hungry Owl All-Night Grocers",
             "ContactName": "Patricia McKenna",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Associate",
             "CustomerID": "HUNGO"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('ISLAT')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Island Trading",
             "ContactName": "Helen Bennett",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "ISLAT"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('KOENE')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Kniglich Essen",
             "ContactName": "Philip Cramer",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Associate",
             "CustomerID": "KOENE"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LACOR')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "La corne d'abondance",
             "ContactName": "Daniel Tonini",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "LACOR"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LAMAI')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "La maison d'Asie",
             "ContactName": "Annette Roulet",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager",
             "CustomerID": "LAMAI"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LAUGB')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Laughing Bacchus Wine Cellars",
             "ContactName": "Yoshi Tannamuri",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Assistant",
             "CustomerID": "LAUGB"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LAZYK')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Lazy K Kountry Store",
             "ContactName": "John Steel",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "LAZYK"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LEHMS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Lehmanns Marktstand",
             "ContactName": "Renate Messner",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Representative",
             "CustomerID": "LEHMS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LETSS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Let's Stop N Shop",
             "ContactName": "Jaime Yorres",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "LETSS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LILAS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "LILA-Supermercado",
             "ContactName": "Carlos Gonzlez",
             "ContactTitle": "Accounting Manager",
             "CustomerID": "LILAS"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LINOD')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "LINO-Delicateses",
             "ContactName": "Felipe Izquierdo",
             "ContactTitle": "Owner",
             "CustomerID": "LINOD"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('LONEP')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Lonesome Pine Restaurant",
             "ContactName": "Fran Wilson",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Manager",
             "CustomerID": "LONEP"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('MAGAA')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti",
             "ContactName": "Giovanni Rovelli",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager",
             "CustomerID": "MAGAA"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('MAISD')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Maison Dewey",
             "ContactName": "Catherine Dewey",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Agent",
             "CustomerID": "MAISD"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('MEREP')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Mre Paillarde",
             "ContactName": "Jean Fresnire",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Assistant",
             "CustomerID": "MEREP"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('MORGK')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "Morgenstern Gesundkost",
             "ContactName": "Alexander Feuer",
             "ContactTitle": "Marketing Assistant",
             "CustomerID": "MORGK"
         },
         {
             "__metadata": {
                 "uri": "http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers('NORTS')",
                 "type": "odata2.namespace.customers"
             },
             "CompanyName": "North/South",
             "ContactName": "Simon Crowther",
             "ContactTitle": "Sales Associate",
             "CustomerID": "NORTS"
         }
         ...
     ]
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the odata.raml file.  Just like any other Mulesoft project its the implementation that will populated the payload that adheres to the contract definition you are offering to you consumers.

Once you have updated your RAML type in the odata.raml you will need to go into the api.xml (Mule Config file) and update the mule flow that is populating the data.  You will simply count the records returned from the DB query and populate your payload accordingly to match the Data Type or you can run a DB count query to let the DB do the counting work. At the end of the day your approach will be based on your system and the needs that it may have.

Comment: I can get the count after the database returns the query response. However, I don't know where to put the count such that  http://localhost:8081/api/odata.svc/customers returns it. I tried adding it to the message transform:

    `{
 entries: `[payload`],
        count: flowVars.count
    }`

But this only works with the non-odata API http://localhost:8081/api/customers